# Vue select slot scope is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-select

I've been debugging for 8 hours trying to find out why this vue-select code is not working, but still no luck. when I run it, it show an error "**option is undefined**".  I'm using npm to install vue-select plugin into my project. I put the following html code in my twig template.  I did follow the instructions on  [vue-select page](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/Advanced/Templating.html)

```
<div id="myapp">
        <v-select :options="myoptions" label="title">
            <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
                <span class="fa" :class="option.icon"></span>
                    {{ option.title }}
            </template>
        </v-select>
</div>
```

Here's the rest of my js implementation code.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueSelect from 'vue-select';        
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect)

new Vue({
    el: '#myapp',
    data: function () {
        return {
            myoptions: [
                {
                    title: 'Read the Docs',
                    icon: 'fa-book',
                    url: 'https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select'
                },
                {
                    title: 'View on GitHub',
                    icon: 'fa-github',
                    url: 'https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select'
                },
                {
                    title: 'View on NPM',
                    icon: 'fa-database',
                    url: 'https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select'
                },
                {
                    title: 'View Codepen Examples',
                    icon: 'fa-pencil',
                    url: 'https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What did you provide via the myoptions property?

Comment: I've updated my question to add more information.

Comment: This should work. Try adding `<pre>{{ myoptions }}</pre>` right before `<v-select>...</v-select>` to see if the data binding works.

Comment: I just done add and run that code and it does print out the content of "myoptions". The data binding is work.

Comment: If you have installed the plugin via NPM vs. CDN, then the documentation states to import and register the component as follows:                                            
`import Vue from 'vue'
import vSelect from './components/Select.vue'

Vue.component('v-select', vSelect)` You can also register it using the `components` object in your component itself

Comment: thanks @DerekFulginiti - I did follow the import and register component. Still not working.  It could be a Vue js version...but I'm not too sure.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I've found the problem, it's my code implementation was incorrect. I didn't import the vue component correctly into my template. It's working fine now.

Comment: better to say what was incorrect and what to watch out for while implementing

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test component which is working perfectly as expected.
My vue dependencies are as follows

```
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-select": "^2.4.0"
  },
```

App.vue component

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-select :options="options" label="title">
            <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
                <span class="fa" :class="option.icon"></span>
                    {{ option.title }}
            </template>
    </v-select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: function() {
        return {
            options: [
                {
                    title: 'Read the Docs',
                    icon: 'fa-book',
                    url: 'https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select'
                },
                {
                    title: 'View on GitHub',
                    icon: 'fa-github',
                    url: 'https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select'
                },
                {
                    title: 'View on NPM',
                    icon: 'fa-database',
                    url: 'https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select'
                },
                {
                    title: 'View Codepen Examples',
                    icon: 'fa-pencil',
                    url: 'https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/vue-select'
                }
            ]
        }
      }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks @Nuwan - I've added and run the code you provided.  I still got the same error.  ReferenceError: "option is not defined"

Comment: @fkaufusi you should try the given example as it is on this page. https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/Advanced/Templating.html.

Comment: Yep, did follow that link, but no luck.  I'm thinking it might be a Version of the Vue that I'm using that caused the problem...i'm not sure.

Comment: @fkaufusi 
i have just updated the code with a full App.vue component which is tested and working well.My vue version also mentioned